# Outer Regularity of the Lebesgue measure on the Hilbert brick

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, metric-spaces, lebesgue-measure

Is the product measure on the Hilbert brick $I=[0,1]^\mathbb{N}$ outer regular (that is measure of every set is the inf of measures of open sets, containing it)?

Comment: You will have better luck searching for "Hilbert cube", rather than "Hilbert brick".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is outer regular.

First of all, since $I$ has only countably many factors, the 
product $\sigma$-field coincides with the Borel $\sigma$-field,
that is, $({\cal B}([0,1]))^{\mathbb N}={\cal B}([0,1]^{\mathbb N})$.
(see Proposition 8.1.5. on page 256 of [C]).
So the product measure is a Borel measure.

Secondly, every finite Borel measure on a Polish space is regular,
so you are done. (see Proposition 8.1.10. on page 258 of [C]).

**Reference:**

[C] *Measure Theory (first edition)* by Donald L. Cohn,  Birkhäuser, 1980.